# How to take image path from file and display image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sub1").click(function()
          {

          $.get("movie.txt",function(data)
         {
            var items=data.split(',');

            for(var i=1;i<items.length;)
             {
                $("#imgID").src=items[i];
             }

               });
            });
           });
      <input type="button" value="sub" id="sub1" />
     <p class="name"> </p>
     <img  src="" id="imgID" height="50" width="50" />

      <p class="type"> </p>
     </body>
```

enter code here

the text file i have is harrypotter.jpe,ironman.jpe,xmen.jpe
I am taking image path mentioned in the file and attaching it to img element.
I have to display all images which are there in the file

Comment: putting all image into one img? can you share what is shown if you co do `console.log(data)`

Comment: So you have array of paths?? and how you want to append them to just one `<img>`

Comment: `$("#imgID").attr('src',items[i]);` but this will change the `src` of image till it reach to last path .. so you'll just notice the last image shown

Comment: I need to show all images which are in the file

Comment: if you want to show all you need to append img for each image path